# Nmos trigerring in 4-20mA converter

Tags: converter, nmos, 4-20ma

Here is the circuit I am trying to understand:

[image]

It comes from the following application note from LT:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/D61_EN-Convert.pdf

I am wondering how the Nmos will ever be triggered. Now from my point of view, the op-amp's negative input should track the voltage on the positive input, setting transistor M2's source voltage to Vin. Now since the op-amp is in the voltage follower configuration, the voltage at M2's gate would also be Vin.

Now that seems to me like Vgs would always be 0V and the FET would never turn on.

I am absolutely certain that my analysis is wrong, I am just not seeing where.

Thank you in advance for all advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Triggered" suggests something that will suddenly switch from one state to another. That's probably not the right word.

As this is an analog circuit we can expect M2 to turn on gradually under certain conditions. "Turned on" would be a better term.

Since the feedback is taken *after* M2 it means that the output of the op-amp will go as high as it needs to to turn on M2 enough to get the feedback voltage to match the input voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT4yQK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Running the CircuitLab DC Solver for 4 V in results in 8 V at NODE1.*

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the output voltage would be Vin + the threshold voltage of the FET? 

PS: Thanks for the vocabulary nuance, i am used to dealing with FETs as switches ;)

Comment: Your understanding about the feedback is correct. This application is a nice example of feedback correction. The feedback causes the output to correct for a large offset and probably some non-linearity introduced by the FET. I wasn't sure whether "triggered" was a language translation issue (given your French / Belgian-looking name) or just the wrong choice of words. I think the concept of turning on like a valve or tap gives a better description of the action. In any case, you seem to have grasped the principle. Thank you for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mistake is assuming the opamp is in voltage follower mode.  The output of the opamp will be whatever it needs to be (within its capabilities) to force the inverting input to match the non-inverting.

The output of the opamp will rarely be Vin.  The feedback is on the other side of the MOSFET.